# yii dataprovider pagination after post

Tags: php, yii, pagination

I have a search form. I would like to pagination the result.

`$criteria` something like this:

```
     if($_POST["tipus"] != 4){
            $criteria->compare('t.tipus',$_POST["tipus"],true);
        }
        if($_POST["varos"] != 0){
            $criteria->compare('`apartman`.`city`', $_POST["varos"], true);
        }
        if($_POST["ferohely"] != 0){
            $criteria->compare('t.ferohely', $_POST["ferohely"], true);
        }
```

My dataprovider:

```
     $dataProvider= new CActiveDataProvider('UserAndApartman', array(
                    'criteria'=>$criteria,
                    'sort'=>array(
                        'defaultOrder'=>'t.id DESC',

                    ),
                    'pagination'=>array(
                                  'pageSize'=>2,
                              ),
                    ));}

 $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'kereses_eredmenyek_view',
));
```

So if i click on the second page, the post doesn't come again. How can i post it automatic?Can i get the `$dataprovider` with pagination?

Comment: With your code pagination is working fine. Not quite sure what you are asking for?

Comment: U must use form method get not post, and get params from $_GET array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You're using $_POST, the $_POST['tipus'] and other data is lost when
>   you're navigating to the next page, since you're not posting it to
>   page 2, 3 etc. You can do two things:

Store the $_POST['tipus'] in a session, so the next page 'knows' what year it has to use.
Store it in the url as a $_GET parameter, so instead of $_POST['tipus'] use $_GET['tipus']. When you navigate to page 2, the $_GET['tipus'] is available in the url on the next page.
The last one is the easiest one i think, and that's how i usually use it.
IF you use the get method, change the CActiveForm line to this:

```
 <?php $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
             'id'=>'fromid',
             'method' => 'get'
    )); ?>
```